# Smallest sum of diagonals for a convex quadrilateral of perimeter $8$

Tags: geometry

> What is the smallest value, on all convex quadrilaterals with
> perimeter 8, of the sum of the lengths of your two diagonals?

My guess was to minimize, with Lagrange multiplers, r, subject to b,c.d:

r = $\sqrt{x²+y²-2xycos(\alpha)} + \sqrt{x²+t²-2xtcos(\beta)}$

b: x + y + z + t = 8

c: $\alpha < \pi$

d: $\beta < \pi$

But i am not sure if this will give us some value, and i think too that this is not the better way to solve the question.

Since my knowledge in geometry is not to vast, i can not see any other way, so i am posting here to ask a tip to attack this problem.

Comment: Look carefully at your picture. You don't have the lengths of the two diagonals. In fact, since there are two ways to get each diagonal, those two equations will give more constraints. Interesting question.

Comment: OOps @TedShifrin you are right, i missed the terms, now it is right.
As you pointed, there are two ways to get each diagonal... This is going to be problematic, all the arithmetic that will be involved here is inevitable?

Comment: Just from a casual inspection, it seems like the minimum ($4$), is obtained as the limit of a sequence of narrowing rhombi, which means it cannot actually be obtained (the limit is a degenerate quadrilateral). Perhaps you would be better off asking for the greatest lower bound.

Comment: I do not think the question is stated correctly. For a convex quadrilateral, using triangle inequality, it is easy to see that the sum of diagonals is _greater than_ half of the sum of its sides and less than the sum of its sides. So all you can say is that the sum is $\gt 4$.

Comment: @Math Lover Agree. There is only an inferior limit $4$, not a minimum, just like there is no maximum but only a limsup, that is $8$.